# Command-line SMTP Server?

Tags: windows-7, smtp

Is there a free command-line-based, *lightweight* SMTP **server** for Windows?

All I'm looking for is the ability to send HTML emails from the command-line, using a standalone EXE, with the program *being* its own server (rather than using some other server like Gmail).

By "lightweight" I mean there should be a single executable, or -- if not possible -- it should come with at most a handful of supporting DLLs, and run standalone (i.e. without installing anything).

#### Specifically:

- I am ***not*** looking for `hMailServer`. It may be awesome, but it's still bloated for sending a single email. I just need a command-line tool I can have handy on a flash drive or a recovery environment -- something that does **not** require installation.
- The server needs to support TLS -- i.e., it should be able to send mail to major providers like Gmail, which require encryption.
- IIS fails every test: it's (1) not lightweight and (2) not standalone.

---

For those who claim Gmail doesn't need encryption:

```
$ telnet smtp.gmail.com 25
Trying 209.85.225.108...
Connected to gmail-smtp-msa.l.google.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 mx.google.com ESMTP a9sm264065ibi.26
HELO
250 mx.google.com at your service
MAIL FROM: my_email@gmail.com
530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. a9sm264065ibi.26
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: GMail doesn't require TLS or any type of encryption for SMTP.  (I just confirmed this by making a raw connection with PuTTY on TCP port 25 and manually sent a message to myself without only four commands, none of which involved any encryption.)

Comment: @Randolf: What were the commands? Each time I tried, it told me I have to use TLS...

Comment: Standard SMTP commands -- HELO, MAIL FROM, RCPT TO, DATA (QUIT is outside of that because a successful return code following a properly completed DATA command is all that's required to send a message; using QUIT to end the session is still important though).

Comment: Regarding "the program _being_ its own server," what you're looking for is what's called a "direct-to-MX mailer" that performs its own lookups for MX records (so that you don't have to specify an SMTP server).  If you don't need something that will queue your message and retry later on, then a command-line tool can work quite well for that.  Otherwise, I suggest David Harris' wonderful Mercury/32 mail server (doesn't use the Registry -- it's a text file configuration only) in which you can simply create a text file in the queue:  http://www.pmail.com/overviews/ovw_mercury.htm

Comment: @Randolph: How come I'm getting that error message regarding TLS? Am I issuing the wrong commands or something?
And thanks for the link, I'll take a look at that!

Comment: Try adding your hostname as a parameter to the HELO command (I believe a hostname is required, although there are many SMTP servers that don't comply with standards).

Comment: @Randolph: I tried; it made no difference.

Comment: You have a space after the colon for the MAIL FROM command (I didn't notice this earlier), but spaces aren't permitted in eMail addresses (unless properly quoted).  You also need to enclose your eMail addresses within angle brackets.  This all applies to the MAIL FROM and RCPT TO commands.  See section 3.3 on page 19 of RFC 5321 (Simple Mail Transfer Protocol):  http://rfc5321.openrfc.org/

Comment: Also, you should be using the SMTP server that is defined in the MX record in the "gmail.com" DNS zone.  The one with the highest priority (5) is:  `gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com`

Comment: @Randolph: :O OMG, it worked! So it was an issue with the server... interesting, thanks a lot for the info. But how do you figure out which server you need to connect to, when all you have is the email address the user gives you? Is there a way to look it up with DNS or something?
Thanks!

Comment: You have to look it up for every site.  In the DNS zone there are usually MX records (if not, then just use the domain name itself, but this is always a last resort as MX records are always preferred).  With each MX record will be a Priority and a Hostname (IP addresses are not allowed, and many SMTP servers will fail to deliver if an IP address is specified in an MX record); always choose the higher priorities (lower values) first.

Comment: @Randolph: Interesting, thanks a lot for the info; that's really helpful! (BTW, my emails went to spam, lol...)

Comment: @Mehrdad Is it actually a server? did you check?

Comment: @RandolfRichardson You soudn familiar with Blat. The question asked for an SMTP Server. Is this actually a server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use [Blat](http://www.blat.net/) to send mails from the command line and have also used this in programs to send mail as well.  It is a single executable.

[image]

Comment: I just tried it with `blat Email.txt -to my_email@gmail.com -server smtp.gmail.com -f my_email` and I got `Blat v2.6.2 w/GSS encryption (build : Feb 25 2007 12:06:19)`

`Sending Email.txt to my_email@gmail.com`
`Login name is my_email`
`The SMTP server does not like the sender name.`
`Have you set your mail address correctly?`

Comment: Right, gmail needs SSL.  For this I use another light program called stunnel http://www.stunnel.org/  You set up stunnel to run on a local port, say 2099, and then tell blat to send to 127.0.0.1:2099  Not pretty, but still lightweight and it works.  I even used this stunnel trick to get Sharepoint to send to gmail accounts. Good luck!

Comment: The only problem with "blat" is that it doesn't perform its own DNS lookups for MX records -- you have to specify the server.  +1 because this is a good solution otherwise though (and there are dozens of alternatives, all of which don't seem to perform their own MX record lookups).

Comment: Is this a server?  "What is Blat (and what does it do)?

http://www.blat.net/?faq/index.html#what_is_blat_(and_what_does_it_do)  "What is Blat (and what does it do)?   Blat is a small, efficent SMTP command line mailer for Windows. It is the SMTP *sending* part of an eMail User Agent (MUA) or eMail client. As such, Blat sends eMail via SMTP (or internet eMail) from the command line, or CGI, ..."  <-- looks like not a server.

Comment: And regarding the -install option.  from the same page http://www.blat.net/?faq/index.html#cl__why_should_i_run_blat_install...  "CL - Why should I run Blat -install...?

Because it simplifies the command line by storing any or all of the following in the registry
  SMTP Server Address
  Sender's Address   "  <-- So looks like that option doesn't make it a server.